# Magento Order Id doesn't match Paypal invoice_id (IPN)

Tags: orders, paypal-express

I have some IPN request failing.
We found out the issue is because the order Id sent to Paypal is, for some reason different (one behind) ex:

- Paypal register ID: 1000010
  ( this id doesn't exist in magento, there is an 'hole' in order progression )
- Magento real order ID is: 1000011

Does anybody experience something similar ? how can we track down the issue ?